# Can I somehow extract a variable from an object and set it to a default if `undefined` in a one-liner?

Tags: typescript

When extracting a variable from an object, is there a way to already check there if it's `undefined` and set a default? I'm basically trying to achieve the below code in one line:

```js
let { name } = user
name ??= "John"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let { name = "John" } = user;
```

(destructuring on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))